# Error while installing MSI package

Tags: .net, windows-installer

I ran an MSI package on my machine[.Net 3.5 application] and it is giving following error while installation:

"This advertised application will not be installed because
it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change
the installation user interface option of the package to
basic"

Ho do I get rid of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: How about you contact the person supplying the MSI?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to run the installer as an Administrator.**

Right-click on the icon for the MSI file, and select "Run as administrator" from the context menu:

[image: Run as administrator]